# lookup in ssrs and return a value

Tags: reporting-services

I have a table with three columns, in column 1 I have a name and column 2 I have a quantity.

I want to look up column 1 and return the value in column 2.

I used to the expression below and it wouldn't return what I wanted.

```
=Lookup(fields!NAME.Value, "Paul" ,1 , 0)
```

Could anybody tell me what expression I need to use?

Comment: Could you provide examples of what data is in each of your columns, and what you want the expression to return?

Answer (score 0):

You are close, sort of. To use the Lookup function properly, you need to change some things. Here is an example using the Lookup function.

`=Lookup(Fields!Field1.Value, Fields!Field1.Value, Fields!Field2.Value, "DatasetB")`

It takes 4 parameters. The first is the field/value from the current (in scope) data set that you want to be the value to match in the lookup data set. The second is the field in the lookup data set to match on. The third in the field to return when a match is found, and the last parameter is the name of the lookup data set.

Based on the expression in your question, it may actually work like this:

`=Lookup("Paul" , Fields!NAME.Value, Fields!QUANTITY.Value , "DataSet2")`

Of course, hard coding the name in the first parameter is probably not what you want to do.